# Relative Layout alignment precedence

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Which takes precedence - layout_alignParentEnd or layout_toEndOf? It seems like layout_toEndOf does, but I would like layout_alignParentEnd to.

I'm trying to align two views on the same horizontal plane, where the view on the left is left aligned and the right is right-aligned. However, if the view on the left has a large width (variable-length text), the view on the right should shrink. Below is how I have it right now, but it seems like the layout_toEndOf is taking precedence over layout_alignParentEnd, when I would like it to always be end-aligned.

Thoughts?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_aligned_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_large" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_aligned_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/left_aligned_view" />
```

Comment: I am not able to get your motive.

Comment: To have two horizontally aligned views, with one aligned at start and one aligned at end, but to never overlap if one grows.

Comment: What will happen if the length of text is greater than the width of both text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/left_aligned_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_large" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_aligned_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_aligned_view" />
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but best practice is to use End / Start for RTL languages.